# How to start Appium server 2.0 Programmatically

Tags: java, appium, appium-desktop

I am aware of starting Appium 1.x programmatically but not able to do it for Appium 2.0

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.usingAnyFreePort();
    builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("<path to Node>\\node.exe"));
    builder.withAppiumJS(new File("<path to Appium>\\appium"));
    HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
    environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
    builder.withEnvironment(environment);
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

install appium 2.0 using below command

```
npm install -g appium@next
```

Make sure there path for nodejs in system environment variable
In User Variable add new Key NODE_PATH and APPIUM_PATH

For NODE_PATH put value as C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

For APPIUM_PATH put value as C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules.bin

You add below line to your code to above
builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withArgument(() -> "--base-path", "/wd/hub").withArgument(() -> "--plugins", "images");

This is complete code

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withArgument(() -> "--base-path", "/wd/hub").withArgument(() -> "--plugins", "images");
        builder.usingAnyFreePort();
        builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"));
        builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\<user_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium"));
        HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
        environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
        builder.withEnvironment(environment);
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "path_to_app\\app\\Learn_Android_With_Source_Code.apk");

        androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
        androidDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return androidDriver;
```